# Node.js - Sequelize Far Models Relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

using [sequelizejs](http://sequelizejs.com) i have three models

- `country`
- `city`
- `location`

(`country` has many `city`) and (`city` has many `location`) as (`country`<  `city`<`location`)
, what if i want to query all `location` and have attribute `country` in each of them ***without***  having `city` model included as so:

```
// I tried this
 Location.belongsTo(City)
 City.belongsTo(Country)
 Location.findById(1,{ include : [{ model:City, include:[Country] }] });

// What i get is
{
  id:1
  name:'location name'
  country: {
     id:6
     name:'country name'
     city: {
         id:4
         name:'city name'
     }
  }
}

// What i want is - No country -
{
  id:1
  name:'location name'
  city: {
     id:4
     name:'city name'
  }
}
```

Is there any way i can achieve this, what if i have *10* models far relationship and i want to get the *first* and the *10th* nested in each other what is the terminology any ideas ...